# TreeView Search Different tabs

Tags: vb.net, search, tabs, treeview

Hey I am having a problem with a piece of code here I have a Tree view box that is link also to a postcode search and a surename search.. well they are more of filters. But I have linked the Treeview so it will populate the Fields once clicked on but it only works on the first tab and i was wondering how i would get this too work?

This is the code for the loadMemberTree

```
  Sub LoadMemberTree()
    '**Loads Client List

    ' Error Checking
    On Error GoTo Err_LoadMemberTree

    ' Dimension Local Variables
    Dim uRecSnap As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim uPar As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim uNode As TreeNode

    Dim iCategoryID As Integer = 0
    Dim iCategoryCnt As Integer = 0
    Dim iMemberID As Integer = 0
    Dim iMemberCnt As Integer = 0
    ' Check For Open Connection
    If uDBase Is Nothing Then
        OpenConnection()
        bConnection = True
    End If

    ' Run Stored Procedure - Load Client List (Based on Search Value)
    uCommand = New ADODB.Command
    With uCommand
        .ActiveConnection = uDBase
        .CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@Surname", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 30)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@Surname").Value = txtSearchSurname.Text
        uPar = .CreateParameter("@Postcode", ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 80)
        .Parameters.Append(uPar)
        .Parameters("@Postcode").Value = txtSearchPostcode.Text
        .CommandText = "Member_LoadRecordsByCategory"

        uRecSnap = .Execute
    End With


    ' Suppress TreeView Repaint / Clear TreeView
    tvwMember.BeginUpdate()
    tvwMember.Nodes.Clear()
    tvwMember.ShowNodeToolTips = True


    ' Populate List
    Do Until uRecSnap.EOF
        If iMemberID <> uRecSnap("CategoryID").Value Then
            uNode = tvwMember.Nodes.Add(Format(uRecSnap("CategoryID").Value, "00"), uRecSnap("CategoryDescription").Value)
            uNode.Tag = "C:" & Format(uRecSnap("CategoryID").Value, "00") & ":0000:"
            iCategoryID = uRecSnap("CategoryID").Value
            iCategoryCnt = iCategoryCnt + 1
            iMemberID = 0
            iMemberCnt = 0
        End If
        If (IsDBNull(uRecSnap("MemberID").Value)) = False Then
            If iMemberID <> uRecSnap("MemberID").Value Then
                uNode = tvwMember.Nodes(iCategoryCnt - 1).Nodes.Add(Format(uRecSnap("MemberID").Value, "0000"), uRecSnap("FullName").Value)
                uNode.Tag = "M:" & Format(uRecSnap("CategoryID").Value, "00") & ":" & Format(uRecSnap("MemberID").Value, "0000") & ":"
                iMemberID = uRecSnap("MemberID").Value
                iMemberCnt = iMemberCnt + 1
            End If
        End If

        uRecSnap.MoveNext()
    Loop
    uRecSnap.Close()

    ' Repaint TreeView.
    tvwMember.EndUpdate()
    tvwMember.Refresh()

    ' Close Connection
    If bConnection Then CloseConnection()
    uRecSnap = Nothing

  Err_LoadMemberTree:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        sErrDescription = Err.Description
        WriteAuditLogRecord(Me.Name, "LoadClientTree", "Error", sErrDescription)
        MsgBox("System Error occurred" & Chr(13) & "LoadClientTree" & Chr(13) & sErrDescription,     MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ICOM - Error Reporting")
    End If
```

This is code runs when you click on the treeview box in design view

```
Private Sub tvwMember_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvwMember.AfterSelect

    ' Dimension Local Variables
    Dim iMemberID As Integer

    iMemberID = Val(tvwMember.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString.Substring(5, 4))
    tabMember.Enabled = (iMemberID <> 0)

    If iMemberID = 0 Then
        ' Clear Details Data
        lblMemberIDValue.Text = "0000"
        txtMembershipNo.Text = ""
        cmbCategory.SelectedIndex = 0
        dtpDateJoined.Value = Now
        txtTitle.Text = ""
        txtForename.Text = ""
        txtSurname.Text = ""
        txtAddition.Text = ""
        txtJobTitle.Text = ""
        txtDepartment.Text = ""
        txtInstitution.Text = ""
        txtAddress1.Text = ""
        txtAddress2.Text = ""
        txtAddress3.Text = ""
        txtTown.Text = ""
        txtPostcode.Text = ""
        txtPhoneNo.Text = ""
        txtMobileNo.Text = ""
        txtEMailAddress.Text = ""
        txtWebsite.Text = ""

        ' Clear Mailing Address Data
        txtMAddress1.Text = ""
        txtMAddress2.Text = ""
        txtMAddress3.Text = ""
        txtMTown.Text = ""
        txtMPostcode.Text = ""
        txtMPhoneNo.Text = ""
        txtMMobileNo.Text = ""
        txtMEMailAddress.Text = ""
        cmbCommittee1.SelectedIndex = 0
        cmbCommittee2.SelectedIndex = 0
        cmbCommittee3.SelectedIndex = 0
        cmbCommittee4.SelectedIndex = 0
        cmbCommittee5.SelectedIndex = 0
        txtRepresentativeName1.Text = ""
        txtRepresentativeName2.Text = ""
        txtRepresentativeName3.Text = ""
        txtRepresentativeName4.Text = ""
        txtRepresentativeName5.Text = ""

    Else
        tvwMember.Tag = iMemberID
        '       txtSearchMemberID.Text = tvwMember.SelectedNode.Text
        With objMember
            .MemberID = iMemberID
            .LoadMember()
            lblMemberIDValue.Text = Format(iMemberID, "0000")
            txtMembershipNo.Text = .MemberShipNo
            For iRCnt = 0 To cmbCategory.Items.Count - 1
                If cmbCategory.Items.Item(iRCnt).ToString = .CategoryDescription Then
                    cmbCategory.SelectedIndex = iRCnt
                End If


            Next
            dtpDateJoined.Value = .DateJoined
            txtTitle.Text = .Title
            txtForename.Text = .Forename
            txtSurname.Text = .Surname
            txtAddition.Text = .Addition
            txtJobTitle.Text = .JobTitle
            txtDepartment.Text = .Department
            txtInstitution.Text = .Institution
            txtAddress1.Text = .AddressLine1
            txtAddress2.Text = .AddressLine2
            txtAddress3.Text = .AddressLine3
            txtTown.Text = .Town
            txtPostcode.Text = .Postcode
            txtPhoneNo.Text = .PhoneNo
            txtMobileNo.Text = .MobileNo
            txtEMailAddress.Text = .EMailAddress
            txtWebsite.Text = .WebSite
            txtMAddress1.Text = .MAddressLine1
            txtMAddress2.Text = .MAddressLine2
            txtMAddress3.Text = .MAddressLine3
            txtMTown.Text = .MTown
            txtMPostcode.Text = .MPostCode
            txtMEMailAddress.Text = .MEmailAddress
            txtMPhoneNo.Text = .MPhoneNo
            txtMMobileNo.Text = .MMobileNo




            ' Clear Mailing Address Data
            txtMAddress1.Text = ""
            txtMAddress2.Text = ""
            txtMAddress3.Text = ""
            txtMTown.Text = ""
            txtMPostcode.Text = ""
            txtMPhoneNo.Text = ""
            txtMMobileNo.Text = ""
            txtMEMailAddress.Text = ""
            cmbCommittee1.SelectedIndex = 0
            cmbCommittee2.SelectedIndex = 0
            cmbCommittee3.SelectedIndex = 0
            cmbCommittee4.SelectedIndex = 0
            cmbCommittee5.SelectedIndex = 0
            txtRepresentativeName1.Text = ""
            txtRepresentativeName2.Text = ""
            txtRepresentativeName3.Text = ""
            txtRepresentativeName4.Text = ""
            txtRepresentativeName5.Text = ""
        End With

    End If

    tsbNewMember.Enabled = False
    tsbSaveMember.Enabled = True
    tsbRemoveMember.Enabled = False
    tabMember.SelectedIndex = 0
    tabMember.SelectedIndex = 0
    tsbSaveMember.Enabled = True



End Sub
```

Comment: Cant do that for this project just yet sadly

Comment: but yes you are right